# Uncaught exception from servlet - JSON GAE deployment issue

Tags: json, google-app-engine, maven

I have created a script on browser that calls a servlet which is deployed on GAE. The servlet uses Datastore.
Everytime servlet is called I receive the following error

```
Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
```

For development I use eclipse and Maven.

In pom.xml I have already included org.json 20090211 and javax.validation.

**UPDATE**
In order to better clarify my question I am posting code from servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
        String str;

        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(str);

        }

        String jsonResp = sb.toString();

        JSONParser gparser = new JSONParser();
```

The problem appears on the last line, so I am posting code from JSONParser

```
public class JSONParser {

public ArrayList<String> ReturnGoogleJSON(String ResponseString) throws IOException {



    ArrayList<String> Row = new ArrayList<String>();         

    try {
        JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(ResponseString); // Parse the JSON to a JSONObject

        JSONArray rows =  rootObject.getJSONArray("items") ; // Get all JSONArray rows

        for(int i=0; i < rows.length(); i++) { // Loop over each each row

                JSONObject element =  rows.getJSONObject(i); // Get the element object

                Row.add(element.getString("tag"));
                Row.add(element.getString("link"));
                Row.add(element.getString("priority"));   



        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  Row;

}
```

}

Could anyone help me with this kind of error?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check war/WEB-INF/lib directory of your project in eclipse before upload and make sure that json and other dependent files are present in this directory.

**Edit:**
You may want to check:

- [GAE - ClassNotFoundException after deployment to Appspot server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318667/gae-classnotfoundexception-after-deployment-to-appspot-server?rq=1)
- http://javanto.com/blog/2012/01/11/gae-eclipse-maven-2-0/

Comment: To my knowledge, it seems that everything is set up correctly.

Comment: I have appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.0.jar  json-20090211.jar validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar related to GAE- what else do I need?

Comment: I mean content of war/WEB-INF/lib directory and not about setting build path, can you double confirm you can see all the mentioned jars are present in war/WEB-INF/lib using "Navigator" view?

Comment: I meant content of war/WEB-INF/lib directory as well. This folder includes all the jars that are mentioned in pom.xml.

Comment: I tried using json-20090211.jar in lib folder and in build path and created the servlet to perform simple json operation, application is working locally and online. Can you post your servlet code?

Comment: I posted it as an update in my initial post. Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. Your code looks fine (i assumed that appropriate imports are in-place) 2. Please check "Edit" options from above answer. 3. In 1.8.0 SDK jason dependency is already available, can you remove your existing jar and use jason dependency from google SDK(com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.*)

Comment: I am sorry for the delay. Well, I tried com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.* but no better news. Regarding the deployment to google: I have a maven project but Iam deploying through google application plugin for eclipse (right click to project-> Google->Deploy) Isn't it correct? Thank you in advance.